# incorrect vector output loop error

Tags: c++, vector

My loop is outputting data incorrectly. I have inbound web data that come in sets of 7. I am trying to in insert the 7 records into a vector and then display the vector content followed by a new line.

```
    char buff[BUFSIZ];
    FILE *fp = stdout;
    char * cstr = buff;
    vector<std::string> vrecords;
    while(std::fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fp) != NULL){
            for(int i = 0; i < 7; ++i){
                    vrecords.push_back(buff);
            }
            if (!strcmp(cstr, "Buy\n")) {
                   printf("Found buy!\n");
                   for(int t = 0; t < vrecords.size(); ++t){
                          cout << vrecords[t] << " ";
                    }
            }
            if (!strcmp(cstr, "Sell\n")) {
                   printf("Found sell!\n");
            }
            cout << endl;
    }
```

output:

[output paste](https://bpaste.net/show/c1872661605f)

expected output:

```
Found buy!
198397652
2014-11-14 15:10:10
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517

Found buy!
198397685
2014-11-14 15:10:13
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517

Found buy!
198398295
2014-11-14 15:11:14
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517

Found sell!
203440061
2014-11-21 16:13:13
Sell
0.00825550
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000826
```

inbound data:

```
198397652
2014-11-14 15:10:10
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198397685
2014-11-14 15:10:13
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198398295
2014-11-14 15:11:14
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
203440061
2014-11-21 16:13:13
Sell
0.00825550
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000826
```

Comment: You are using `i` as variables in both your for loops.

Comment: What's `cstr`? Why are you using old C-style input/output and string-handling in C++?

Comment: show definition of `vrecords`

Comment: Did you mean to use `if (!strcmp(buffer, "Buy\n"))` instead of `if (!strcmp(cstr, "Buy\n"))`?

Comment: The pattern match (strcmp) works perfectly and needs to stay as is.

Comment: I recommend you learn how to use a debugger, and then step through the code line by line in the debugger. It will show you what is really happening (like you pushing each line six times into the vector in the outer `for` loop). Hint: You might want to rearrange the order/nesting of those loops.

Comment: strace doesn't show much and gdb runs clean  https://bpaste.net/show/950a6d6b3c79